# Improving quality of characters in images of license plates

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, binary-operators

So I am trying to improve the quality of the characters in the following image (and other license plate images). After localizing and cropping the images, I am wondering what my best option to get rid of those interrupted edges like on the left side of the "M" would be.

preprocessed LP:
[image: preprocessed LP]

I tried out some binary operations like openings and closings and I could imagine that a proper choice of a structuring element would do a good job. Any smart ideas around to make this a nicer input for tesseract? I am using python 2.7. for all of this.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I don't think a decent OCR should have problems reading this as is. You can make it look a bit nicer through morphological operations or just a median filter. Modern license plate characters are usually designed for OCR.

Comment: But what could a helpful morphological operation look like? The ones I tried make the image worse, destroying connections or adding pixels in the wrong places making the image less readable. I am on the training part but also want to improve image quality as much as possible to minimize errors.